# Interop object throws exception If two session of applications are open in C++

Tags: c++, interop, com-interop, marshalbyrefobject, interopservices

I am using `System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetActiveObject(MyApplication);` to initialize my Interop object. When I open two sessions of application and in second session, call the function of interop object, it throws following exception HRESULT 0x80010105:

[image]

Is there a way I can use interop object in two sessions separately ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "session". But all this depends on your application, this is not a pure COM issue. RPC_E_SERVERFAULT probably means your server crashed, which could be a bug, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12538737/403671 there's nothing we could do w/o more information (like reproducing code)

Comment: @SimonMourier By 'session' I mean two instance of an application.

Comment: If by two instances of application, you mean two Windows processes, this is quite irrelevant as a COM client. The client just connects to an object. Whether this object is server by a new process or a second one depends on how the application is coded with regards to COM, as a COM server. The problem is probably on your application side, how it was coded. Again, there's nothing more that can be said w/o any reproducing code.